# How to update cache once a day on the day (00:00:00) in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, caching, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a data set that has to be updated only once every 24 hours. This should happen with the first request of the day at or after 00:00:00. how do we set the cache remember condition for this as it only allows for setting minutes not the time?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Carbon` for that. In the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/cache#cache-usage) we can find an example to expire a cache after 10 minutes:

```
$expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);
Cache::put('key', 'value', $expiresAt);
```

All you want it to determine the end of the day. Luckily [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-modifiers) offers everything:

```
$expiresAt = Carbon::now()->endOfDay();
```

This will give you the last second of the current day 23:59:59. Just add one second to satisfy your requirement:

```
$expiresAt = Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->addSecond();
```

Comment: Not the complete answer, I was trying to find a way to cache at start of day OR first request of day.
Going by
append date to predefined key
if exist 
     return cached result
else
     calculate, cached, return result.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Not the complete answer, I was trying to find a way to cache at start of day OR first request of day. Going by `append date to predefined key`

So what you want is simple, if you want a simple solution you can add a table in your DB and it simply has two attributes: id and date. From here when someone login you check if there was a login that day, if not you do what you have to do.

**EDIT**

well when someone logs-in you update the date in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just correcting the most upvoted answer : `Carbon::now()->endOfDay();` doesnt return the current date at 23h59s but rather the current date at 23h 59s 999ms.

`Carbon::now()->endOfDay();` is closer to 00h than `Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->addSecond();` which equals 00h 00m 999ms.